# Google Tango glitching in the build (Unity 5.6.1)

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, tango

I've made an ARKit app that I was porting to Google Tango. The build works but the augmented object keeps tiling itself when it is visible on the mobile phone. Like this:

[image: It's a 4 stroke engine btw]

There aren't any errors popping up either. It just .. glitches like that. 
I made an empty scene with some random object and that works perfectly fine. In the same project so the build settings are fine I think. And the "Tango Manager" and "Tango Camera" settings are similar on both the scenes.

Anyone face something like this? Or has any solution to this?

You can check out the app from this link: [4 Stroke Engine AR](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/4-stroke-engine-ar/id1324924457?mt=8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for those who are stuck at this (maybe), what solved it for me was to **use Unity 5.3.1f** to make the build. 
I guess Tango SDK for Unity wasn't updated for 5.6. It isn't there for any version above that either.